# Viewing the backtrace ('bt') stack for each instruction in main() using gdb

Tags: gdb, backtrace

This is with reference to the gdb debugger. By placing a breakpoint in a header file or another source code, and not the file that is being executed, it is possible to trace the path starting from the instruction in the main() function (of the file being executed) to the point where the breakpoint is placed (in the header file or another source code), by entering **bt** in gdb (Displaying the stack essentially).

Is it possible to display the stack for every instruction in main() without having to place breakpoints in other files, and then pressing **bt**? At the moment, I am placing breakpoints in various files, and then tracing back their path to the file of my interest. Instead, I want the whole path (the **bt** 'stack') to be displayed for every instruction inside the main() function of my interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a user command combining `stepi` and `bt` like so:

```
(gdb) define sbt
Type commands for definition of "sbt".
End with a line saying just "end".
>stepi
>bt
>end
```

Here is example usage:

```
$ cat t.c
int bar() { return 42; }
int foo() { return bar(); }
int main() { return foo(); }

$ gcc -g t.c
$ gdb -q ./a.out
```

Define `sbt` command as above. Now use it:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40050c: file t.c, line 3.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:3
3       int main() { return foo(); }
(gdb) sbt
0x0000000000400511      3       int main() { return foo(); }
#0  0x0000000000400511 in main () at t.c:3
(gdb)
```

Here simply pressing Enter repeats previous (`sbt`) command.

```
foo () at t.c:2
2       int foo() { return bar(); }
#0  foo () at t.c:2
#1  0x0000000000400516 in main () at t.c:3
(gdb) 
0x00000000004004f9      2       int foo() { return bar(); }
#0  0x00000000004004f9 in foo () at t.c:2
#1  0x0000000000400516 in main () at t.c:3
(gdb) 
2       int foo() { return bar(); }
#0  foo () at t.c:2
#1  0x0000000000400516 in main () at t.c:3
(gdb) 
0x0000000000400501      2       int foo() { return bar(); }
#0  0x0000000000400501 in foo () at t.c:2
#1  0x0000000000400516 in main () at t.c:3
(gdb) 
bar () at t.c:1
1       int bar() { return 42; }
#0  bar () at t.c:1
#1  0x0000000000400506 in foo () at t.c:2
#2  0x0000000000400516 in main () at t.c:3
```

... etc.

P.S. Since you want to examine stack at every instruction, it may make sense to add `x/i $pc` to the `sbt` command as well, so you know what instruction you are about to step over.